# Saving the state of various draggables and droppables to create new html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

How can I save the state of various draggables and droppables (along with their background images) and assign a button to create a new html which adds some of the more features to the existing states?

Comment: By implementing that, which is up to you. There is no general solution for what you ask for.

Comment: I am looking for a constructive idea that can give a newbie like me a little guideline. I am sorry to say that you could have made it better.

Comment: No problem Jack, but your question is pretty vague which makes it hard to answer specifically. I probably could have made it better, but it's also a question of the motivation.

Comment: Sorry for being rude. My apologies.. Can you please suggest me a way to save a state of a single draggable and method to post it? Please remind me if it is still vague for the answer.

Comment: You were not rude, nothing to apologies. I only tried to explain you, that's all. Sorry that I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite ambiguous...

Why don't you look into jQuery:

[Draggables](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

[jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

I assume what you are wanting to achieve would need to be saved into a database, so you would use AJAX to then save the positions from the dragable elements